# How to export full content of GSP into PDF in Grails

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, export, grails-plugin

I tried both export plugin and jasper plugin in a Grails application for exporting GSP content into PDF format. It is working fine for exporting table content to PDF but I want to export full content of GSP into PDF, i.e GSP page contains tabular data as well as Google chart data.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Grails Rendering plugin. As for the Google chart data, I think you need to find a way to render that as an image before including it in the GSP, if you want to export it in the PDF.